# vim transplant color scheme from one host to another

Tags: vim

I mostly use Vim on CentOS, but recently I have to use it on Ubuntu. Ubuntu Vim's default colorscheme is very different from that on CentOS. Besides, I customized a little color in CentOS Vim too. Now is it possible that I export colorscheme in CentOS Vim, and transplant it into Ubuntu Vim? like output a colorscheme file myfavorate.vim, and copy it into /usr/share/vim/vim*/colors?

ADD：
I compared default.vim in CentOS and Ubuntu, files are the same.

Comment: Why not just copy your config over? It should work.

Comment: @Heptite I looked into my config, and it does not help to change Vim colorscheme on Ubuntu to be the same as I have in CentOS. I guess the two environment makes default schemes different.

Comment: It could be one of the distributions is sourcing a colorscheme by default. What's the output of "`:scriptnames`"?

Comment: @Heptite there are several items, the 1st is /etc/vimrc

Comment: Is there a colorscheme in the list?

Comment: The default colorscheme is the same in every Vim on every OS. Your problem is most likely caused by the theme of your terminal emulator, which is what you want to transfer from one machine to the other. How to do it depends on your terminal emulators, an information you didn't share with us.